# Alt+Tab lagging on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, alt-tab

Switching between applications with alt+tab is sometimes really really laggy. Nothing happens for a couple of seconds, then all of a sudden, all keypresses are processed at once, causing the windows to switch around in a quick succession.

I'm not sure if it's any of the applications I run (VS Code, Slack, Outlook, Spotify, etc) that is causing this, or one of the many many corporate bloatware I've been forced to install.

How can I debug this and figure out what is causing the lag? I've thought about something like ProcMon but I don't know if that's a good fit?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Ask your Comapny about what they installed. Try a clean boot with nothing runing and check Alt Tab. Then add apps to the boot sequence.

Comment: It's most probably Windows itself of video card drivers are lagging. For troubleshooting you can check event viewer but I don't belive you can find much there.
Try to use `Win+Tab` instead

Comment: Same thing happens to me, but only when Windows Terminal app is running. Go figure. If i hit alt-tab furiously enough, windows desktop restarts - i can see all UI disappearing with only bg left for a sec - and problem is gone. All seems to be working OK after that.

Comment: Killing the Cortana process seems to be working for me

Answer (score 1):

Disabling News&Interrests helped in like 80% of my app switches, making them instant as expected.

There are still occasional several seconds lags though. Restarting the explorer.exe process seems to help sometimes too, but that's quite inconvenience. I got 64GB RAM, so should not be a swapping issue.